# How to I apply the login function for gmail to gui entry boxes for Python?

Tags: python, email, user-interface, authentication, tkinter

I need to create an entry box for the mail.login function, so that there are entry boxes for the email and password prompt. This program basically gives you information in your inbox, but I want to make it into a GUI instead of just a console application.

```
    import glob, os, imaplib, getpass, email, datetime, sys, poplib, sys
    from tkinter import *

    root =enter code here Tk()

    # logs into  email

    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
    mail.login(input('Gmail Username: '), input('Password: '))

    # Out: list of "folders" aka labels in gmail.

    mail.select("inbox")  # connect to inbox.
    result, data = mail.uid('search', None, 'ALL')
    uids=data[0].split()

    # Searches body structure for attachments

    result, data = mail.uid('fetch', uids[-1], 'BODYSTRUCTURE')
    print(data)

    app = Frame(root)
    app.grid()

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ok, what part of the solution do you need help with? Have you started working through a tkinter tutorial? It will probably teach you everything you need to know.

Comment: @joctaviuscaesar Does my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

There is lots of information out there about how to do things like this with tkinter. Have a look at [tkinterbook](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm) for something that might work for you.

To help you out. Here is an example of creating a simple dialog with tkinter (for python3)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog

class GetUserNamePassword(simpledialog.Dialog):

    def body(self, master):

        tk.Label(master, text="Username:").grid(row=0)
        tk.Label(master, text="Password:").grid(row=1)

        self.e1 = tk.Entry(master)
        self.e2 = tk.Entry(master, show='*')

        self.e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
        return self.e1 # initial focus

    def apply(self):
        first = str(self.e1.get())
        second = str(self.e2.get())
        self.result = (first, second) # or something

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
d = GetUserNamePassword(root)
print(d.result)
```